# What is flash hardware acceleration?

Tags: flash

i was going through the hardware acceleration feature  in Flash 10.1 for Mac. i couldn't understand how it works. Can anyone give a gist  of what is hardware acceleration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It mean that for the rendering they are not using CPU (or software rendering) but are using the GPU. This reduces the load on the CPU and gives better performance. But it is supported only on relatively new Macs.